# Passing a file path via python to a HTML API

Tags: python, html, python-2.7

Good morning,

I am trying to pass a path name that I have had returned via a Python script to a HTML API to play a video.

The script searches for what video is to be played based on standard input, I then need to pass that path to an URL that will then pop that path in the src within the HTML.

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="path passed from python" type="video/mp4">`
```

I am going to host the website locally since the website is going to be displayed via an entity in Maltego and Maltego seems to require a valid URL in the field to be able to execute the "open website" functionality. Ive been googling... and googling... and googling... but I cant find what I am looking for, I am probably asking incorrectly. I understand that there will be some sort pass in the URL:

http://localip/index.html

And the HTML will pick up the variable from that URL, but im not sure how to go about it! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's really not clear what you are asking. And if this is a question about Maltego, whatever that is, then you should tag it as such.

Comment: Maltego is a link analysis tool. But that doesnt matter really. Basically, I am returning a path via python using some search functionality within the OS module. Once it returns the file name I need it concatonates that and gives me a full path. I then need to pass that path to an URL so that when the HTML API opens it it drops that path into the SRC and runs the video.

Comment: OK, but what is your question? If you have a path, what's stopping you concatenating it? And what does "pass that path to a URL" mean?

Comment: The question is:

Python associates that URL with an entity. I tell that entity to open a browser and use its name as the URL. So, it will open http://localip/index.html<path to video> then, then HTML API needs to take that path and dump it into the src. Could I pass a text file into the src? That way the python script can just pass the path to that text file.

Comment: No, you cannot - the source has to be a video file - it cannot be a text file with links to other files.

Comment: So, I either pass that path in the URL and have the HTML pick the path up from the URL, or I have to load the path from the text file, store it in a variable and pass taht variable to the src of the video. Anyone know how to go about either one of those options?